# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop package installed, but can't launch "gnome-terminal", "cannot open display"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have install ubuntu desktop packages on a 12.04 LTS server. X server comes up fine, GUI works fine without any issues.

However, when I tried to issue a terminal, I get "Cannot open display", I find this strange since the X Display is running.

Here is a link to my screenshot I took from VNC viewer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhP6B.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the $DISPLAY variable

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

This variable helps to find which X server to connect to. You can add it to your ~/.bashrc file and in case you want to set it for all users, add it to the /etc/bashrc file instead.